# nth derivative of a radical function

Tags: calculus, derivatives, radicals

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{3x+5}$. Obtain and prove a formula for the nth derivative. I'm having trouble finding the formula for the nth derivative.

I've computed the first three derivatives but not really sure what to do after that.

Comment: What about using induction? 
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=3\times\frac{1}{2}(3x+5)^{-1/2}\\
f''(x)&=3\cdot 3\times \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-1\right)(3x+5)^{-3/2}\\
f'''(x)&=3^3\times \frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right)(3x+5)^{-5/2}\\
\end{align}
And so on.

Comment: have you tried computing the first, second, third derivatives? after a few tries, some kind of pattern should be visible

Comment: I need to find the general formula first, which i'm not sure how to do

Comment: Yes, I've computed the first three derivatives but not sure what to do from there

Comment: http://www.newagepublishers.com/samplechapter/001937.pdf

Comment: Yes, I've done the first three derivatives but don't know how to find the general formula for n

Comment: @Anushan What about $$f^{(n)}(x)=3^n\frac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\left(-\frac{3}{2}\right) \cdots\left(-\frac{2n-3}{2}\right)(3x+5)^{-(2n-1)/2}?$$

Comment: would that count as a general formula for n?

Comment: how would you prove this formula using induction?

Comment: Why did you ask the same question over again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at first the first thee derivatives
$$f(x)=(3x+5)^{1/2}$$
$$f'(x)=\frac{3}{2}(3x+5)^{1/2}$$
$$f''(x)=-\frac{9}{4}(3x+5)^{-3/2}$$
$$f'''(x)=\frac{81}{8}(3x+5)^{-5/2}$$
and can you proceed?

Comment: I've done the first three derivatives already. I don't know how to get the general formula n from here

Comment: $$3/2$$, $$-3^2/2^2$$,$$3^4/2^3$$,... is this clear?

Comment: @Anushan what parts of the formula stay the same? What are changing? How do they change individually?

Comment: I understand that but I have trouble finding the full formula for n